# Nuxt - Cannot remove Event Listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt.js` and have a scroller that scrolls and stops at a fixed point on my page.

When I click to the next page, the method is still looking for the `$ref=nav` and is coming back undefined because it is not there anymore `Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined`

I can add the eventListener but cannot remove the eventListener.

**Listener**

```
mounted(){
   window.addEventListener('scroll', this.stickyScroll);
},
beforeDestroy(){
   window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.stickyScroll);
}
```

**Scroller**

```
stickyScroll(){
   window.document.onscroll = () => {
        let navBar = this.$refs.nav;
        let navBarXPosition = navBar.getBoundingClientRect().x;
        let navScrollSpy = this.$refs.navScrollSpy;
        let navScrollSpyXPosition = navScrollSpy.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
        if(window.scrollY > navBarXPosition && navScrollSpyXPosition > 25){
             this.active = true;
         } else {
             this.active = false;
         }
    }
 },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.document.onscroll = fn` is effectively the same as `window.addEventListener('scroll', fn)`, so `stickyScroll()` *adds* a new event listener for *every* `scroll` event.

The solution is to remove the setting of `window.document.onscroll` so that the contents of the arrow function becomes the contents of `stickyScroll`, which would allow the proper removal of the handler:

```js
stickyScroll() {
  let navBar = this.$refs.nav;
  let navBarXPosition = navBar.getBoundingClientRect().x;
  let navScrollSpy = this.$refs.navScrollSpy;
  let navScrollSpyXPosition = navScrollSpy.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  if (window.scrollY > navBarXPosition && navScrollSpyXPosition > 25) {
    this.active = true;
  } else {
    this.active = false;
  }
}
```